# Error al importar com.toptoche.searchablespinner en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-spinner

tengo un problema que me salta al importar la librería com.toptoche.searchablespinner en mi aplicación android. Este es el error que me salta:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

y este es mi gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ezdev.mayoristatataapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.1'

    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'

    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Cuando dejo de implementar la librería el programa compila sin ningún problema, pero necesito la librería ya que la estoy implementando ya en el código. Y aunque este sincronizada no me resuelve la clase en el xml.
Tengo otra app que esta implementando esta libreria y funciona correctamente, pero con esta app no puedo lograr que corra.

Ya verifique que no este en Offline el gradle

Comment: Aunque se indica el error "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'", te sugiero revisar que màs errores se registran, probablemente es un problema de la dependencia con el OS.

Answer (score 0):

Esto resuelve tu problema:

Adiciona la siguiente linea en **`settings.gradle`** dentro de repositories

```
maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).